# efficient way to merge multiple dataframes and a constant value dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to use `pd.concat` to combine multiple dataframes into a single one. Here is my code

```
inputs = pd.concat([x1_df, x2_df], axis=1)
```

both `x1_df` and `x2_df` are two dataframes with one column only. Right now, I would like to add the third column, which only contains a single value , e.g., `1`.
I used `inputs = pd.concat([x1_df, x2_df, 1], axis=1)` , which does not work. Certainly, I can create a dataframe containing single value first, are there any other efficient ways to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options I could think of right away:

1a. Assign a new column to the resulting concated DataFrame:

```
inputs = pd.concat([x1_df, x2_df], axis=1)
inputs['new_col'] = 1
```

1b. Chain assign after to concated DataFrame:

```
pd.concat([x1_df, x2_df], axis=1).assign(new_col=1)
```

2. Assign a value to one of the DataFrames before concat:

```
pd.concat([x1_df, x2_df.assign(new_col=1)], axis=1)
```

3a. Make a new DataFrame with the value using python then concat the new frame:

```
pd.concat([x1_df, x2_df, pd.DataFrame({'new_col': [1] * len(x1_df)})], axis=1)
```

3b. Make a new DataFrame with the value using [`np.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy-full) then concat the new frame

```
pd.concat([
    x1_df, x2_df, pd.DataFrame({'new_col': np.full(x1_df.shape[0], 1)})
], axis=1)
```

---

All produce the same results:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x1_df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(1, 4)})
x2_df = pd.DataFrame({"B": np.arange(1, 4)})
```

`input`:

```
   A  B  new_col
0  1  1        1
1  2  2        1
2  3  3        1
```

---

Timings via perfplot:

[image: benchmarking results]

| Fastest |  | Slowest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `=` or `np.full` | `assign` | python `list * len` |
| 1a, 3b | 1b, 2 | 3a |

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot


def gen_data(n):
    x1_df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(0, n)})
    x2_df = pd.DataFrame({"B": np.arange(0, n)})
    return x1_df, x2_df


def concat_assign(dfs):
    x1_df, x2_df = dfs
    return pd.concat([x1_df, x2_df.assign(new_col=1)], axis=1)


def assign_after(dfs):
    x1_df, x2_df = dfs
    inputs = pd.concat([x1_df, x2_df], axis=1)
    inputs['new_col'] = 1
    return inputs


def chain_assign_after(dfs):
    x1_df, x2_df = dfs
    return pd.concat([x1_df, x2_df], axis=1).assign(new_col=1)


def concat_new_df_times_len(dfs):
    x1_df, x2_df = dfs
    return pd.concat([
        x1_df, x2_df, pd.DataFrame({'new_col': [1] * len(x1_df)})
    ], axis=1)


def concat_new_df_np_full(dfs):
    x1_df, x2_df = dfs
    return pd.concat([
        x1_df, x2_df, pd.DataFrame({'new_col': np.full(x1_df.shape[0], 1)})
    ], axis=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    out = perfplot.bench(
        setup=gen_data,
        kernels=[
            concat_assign,
            chain_assign_after,
            assign_after,
            concat_new_df_times_len,
            concat_new_df_np_full
        ],
        labels=[
            'concat_assign',
            'chain_assign_after',
            'assign_after',
            'concat_new_df_times_len',
            'concat_new_df_np_full'
        ],
        n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
        equality_check=None
    )
    out.save('perfplot_results.png', transparent=False)
```